# CodeIgniter session value as images

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my project, I am using pagination and I used these statements to get the page number detail:

```
$page=$this->uri->segment(3);
$this->session->set_userdata('page',$page);
echo $this->session->userdata('page');
```

When I print this session value in that page itself, I get the value correctly and when I click on the particular link and then print that data, I am getting the value like `'images'`.
Why is this happening?

However, when I write the statements like

```
$page=$this->uri->segment(2);
$this->session->set_userdata('page',$page);
echo $this->session->userdata('page');
```

it's working fine.

My URL is: http://localhost/CI/user/index/4

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with you, the session variable always get value 'images'. Then i realize that: if we made a session variable, then we must call redirect() directly. 
This is my example:

```
$page=$this->uri->segment(3);
$this->session->set_userdata('page',$page);
redirect('control/function2');
```

Then, you can get continue your code in the 'function2'.

Answer (score 1):

Solved the issue by writing another function, setting the session and redirecting to above function like this:

```
function set_session(){
  $id=$this->uri->segment(3);
   $this->session->set_userdata('id',$id);
   redirect('set_uri_session');
}

function set_uri_session(){
$id=$this->uri->segment(3);
$this->session->set_userdata('id',$id);
echo $this->session->userdata('id');
}
```